# How can I get the list of available platforms in cordova?

Tags: cordova

I'm looking for something similar to `cordova platform list` but not inside a cordova project.   I'm writing a script that needs to know what platforms are available.  I'd like to base this on platforms that will actually be buildable on the current system, but for now I'll be happy with output similar to the above command.

Answer (score 0):

All of the platforms that Cordova interfaces with have command line tools, so you could make a call to each of those and figure which are actually setup and capable of calling to.

I am not familiar with all of them, but for iOS you can run `xcode-select -p` which will return the path that xcode is installed to. And for android you could run `android list sdk` which will return a list available SDKs if available.

For any others, search for their command line tools and see if there is a `list` or `version` call you can make.

Comment: I'm hoping to find something more forward compatible than that.  I'm currently looking into the cordova source for a hook or at least a way to make one.